# UserMessagingPlatform invalid response from server

Tags: android, admob

I'm trying to add user consent into my app using UMP, as defined in https://developers.google.com/admob/ump/android/quick-start. Unfortunately, each call to requestConsentInfoUpdate() results in a generic "invalid response from server" error. My AdMob account has a GDPR message defined and turned on. The only information I could find relates to creating a Funding Choices account, but this is no longer possible since Google migrates away from FC. Is there a way to show them form, or debug the issue in-depth?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Turns out, this happens when the AdMob account is still under verification.

Comment: so how to test it if the app is under development!!

Comment: @MostafaOnaizan you just need to wait for verification.